# Error while saving map value in Spark dataframe(scala) - Expected column, actual Map[int,string]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, key-value

I have key values pair in Map[int,string]. I need to save this value in Hive table using spark dataframe. But i am getting error - `Expected column, actual Map[int,string]`

Code:

```
val dbValuePairs = Array(2019,10)
val dbkey = dbValuePairs.map(x => x).zipWithIndex.map(t => (t._2, t._1)).toMap

val dqMetrics = spark.sql("select * from dqMetricsStagingTbl")
  .withColumn("Dataset_Name", lit(Dataset_Name))
  .withColumn("Key", dbkey)
dqMetrics.createOrReplaceTempView("tempTable")

spark.sql("create table if not exists hivetable AS select * from tempTable")

dqMetrics.write.mode("append").insertInto(hivetable)
```

Please help!  Error in `withColumn("Key", dbkey)` line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at Spark function `withColumn` signature:

```
def withColumn(colName: String, col: Column): DataFrame
```

it takes two arguments: `colName` as `String` and `col` as `Column`.

your `dbkey` type is `Map[Int, Int]` that is not `Column`:

```
val dbkey: Map[Int, Int] = dbValuePairs.map(x => x).zipWithIndex.map(t => (t._2, t._1)).toMap
```

if you want store `Map` in your table column you can use `map` function which takes a sequence of `Column`:

```
// from object org.apache.spark.sql.functions
def map(cols: Column*): Column
```

so you can convert your dbkey to `Seq[Column]` and pass it to `withColumn` function:

```
val dbValuePairs = Array(2019,10)
val dbkey: Map[Int, Int] = dbValuePairs.map(x => x).zipWithIndex.map(t => (t._2, t._1)).toMap
val dbkeyColumnSeq: Seq[Column] = dbkey.flatMap(t => Seq(lit(t._2), lit(t._1))).toSeq

val dqMetrics = spark.sql("select * from dqMetricsStagingTbl")
  .withColumn("Dataset_Name", lit(""))
  .withColumn("Key", map(dbkeyColumnSeq:_*))
```